# wp_mail - Remove sitename from email subject

Tags: filters, hooks, email, wp-mail

Can someone tell me how to remove site name from the email subject.

As of now my email subject looks like this:

> **[sitename] - Subject goes here**

I want it to look like this:

> **Subject goes here**

I checked the `wp_mail()` code. There is a [`wp_mail`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail) filter available.

Can someone tell me how to use that filter to alter my email subject?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I wrote some code and it worked very well.

I hope it helps.

Put this in your `functions.php` file

```
//remove sitename from email subject
add_filter('wp_mail', 'email_subject_remove_sitename');
function email_subject_remove_sitename($email) {
  $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);
  $email['subject'] = str_replace("[".$blogname."] - ", "", $email['subject']);    
  $email['subject'] = str_replace("[".$blogname."]", "", $email['subject']);
  return $email;
}
```

Comment: I have done same but when I had replace the blogname , somehow its prepend again, so I had to enter another name inside it. check below code , it might help you

function email_subject_remove_sitename($email) {
  $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);
  $email['subject'] = str_replace("[".$blogname."] - ", "", $email['subject']);    
  $email['subject'] = str_replace("[".$blogname."]", "", $email['subject']);

  $email['subject'] = "NewName | ".$email['subject'];  
  return $email;
}

Answer (score 0):

That file didnt work for me I had to it in wp-includes/pluggable.php

```
if ( isset( $atts['message'] ) ) {
    //$message = $atts['message'];
    $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);
  $subject = str_replace("[".$blogname."] - ", "", $subject);    
  $subject = str_replace("[".$blogname."]", "", $subject);
}
```

Comment: Please don't say you edited a core file.